# Create more then one column in a pivot table with one sql statement

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I need to sort on date in a pivot table project data for the same project number

The project looks like this:

```
"Project nr"   "Task"                "Task deadline"  "Task Type Production"
123             pack                  1 april 2013    Pack
123             Leave production      3 april 2013    Leave Production
123             Flight date           9 april 2013    Flight Date
```

The "Task Type Production" is made to ensure the contents of the field is always consistant
I can only create one column in the pivot table. Is there  a way to display thes info in 3 columns
it will look like this:

```
Project nr ;  Pack   ;  leave production ; flightdate   


SELECT  [TaskDeadline] AS Packed
FROM         MSP_EpmTask_UserView where  [Task Type Production] = 'Packed'
SELECT  [TaskDeadline] AS LeaveProduction
FROM         MSP_EpmTask_UserView where  [Task Type Production] =  'Leave Production' 
SELECT  [TaskDeadline] AS FlightDate
FROM         MSP_EpmTask_UserView where  [Task Type Production] =  'Flight Date'
```

Thanks 
Anne

Answer (score 4):

This can easily be done using an aggregate function and a `CASE` expression:

```
select  [Project nr],
    MAX(case when [Task Type Production] = 'Pack' then [Task deadline] end) as Pack,
    MAX(case when [Task Type Production] = 'Leave Production' then [Task deadline] end) as [Leave Production],
    MAX(case when [Task Type Production] = 'Flight Date' then [Task deadline] end) as [Flight Date]
from MSP_EpmTask_UserView 
group by    [Project nr]
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0889e/1)

If you want to use the `PIVOT` function in SQL Server, then the query will be:

```
select *
from
(
  select [Project nr],[Task deadline], [Task Type Production]
  from MSP_EpmTask_UserView 
) src
pivot
(
  max([Task deadline])
  for [Task Type Production] in ([Pack], [Leave Production],
                                 [Flight Date])
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0889e/3).

Finally this can be done using multiple joins to your table:

```
select t1.[Project nr],
  t1.[Task deadline] pack,
  t2.[Task deadline] [Leave Production],
  t3.[Task deadline] [Flight Date]
from MSP_EpmTask_UserView t1
left join MSP_EpmTask_UserView t2
  on t1.[Project nr] = t2.[Project nr]
  and t2.[Task Type Production] = 'Leave Production'
left join MSP_EpmTask_UserView  t3
  on t1.[Project nr] = t3.[Project nr]
  and t3.[Task Type Production] = 'Flight Date'
where t1.[Task Type Production] = 'Pack'
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0889e/5)

The result of all queries is:

```
| PROJECT NR |       PACK | LEAVE PRODUCTION | FLIGHT DATE |
------------------------------------------------------------
|        123 | 2013-04-01 |       2013-04-03 |  2013-04-09 |
```

Comment: +1 for the options. I like the `case` version, though the `pivot` syntax is just as fast on my box.

Comment: @TimLehner I like to provide other versions of the queries.  I prefer pivot but some people have a hard time with the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a cross-tab or pivot using the traditional method of correlated subqueries:

```
select [Project nr]
    , (select [Task deadline] from MSP_EpmTask_UserView where [Project nr] = t.[Project nr] and [Task Type Production] = 'Pack') as Pack
    , (select [Task deadline] from MSP_EpmTask_UserView where [Project nr] = t.[Project nr] and [Task Type Production] = 'Leave Production') as [Leave Production]
    , (select [Task deadline] from MSP_EpmTask_UserView where [Project nr] = t.[Project nr] and [Task Type Production] = 'Flight Date') as [Flight Date]
from MSP_EpmTask_UserView t
group by [Project nr]
order by [Project nr]

/*
Project nr  Pack       Leave Production Flight Date
----------- ---------- ---------------- -----------
123         2013-04-01 2013-04-03       2013-04-09
*/
```

I've done this in SQL Server 2008 which has the nice `date` datatype, though you can certainly do this with stings or datetime.  This also assumes that there is only one of each date for a particular Project nr.

Also, when possible, try not to put spaces or other special characters in your DB object names that force you to delimit them with brackets.